How can I possible recover data from an M2 SSD on Windows 11?
My windows 11 laptop stopped booting and gave a failed hard drive error (from the bios). I bought a new M2 SSD and have installed windows 11 fresh on it (this is what I'm using now), and have the old M2 SSD in a USB C enclosure.
In Disk Management I can see the disk as having a healthy recovery partition, a healthy EFI system partition, a large Unknown (BitLocker Encrypted) partition and another healthy recovery partition. But I never get asked for a password and I while the disk shows up in the filesystem I cant open it, but get asked if I want to format it.
Chkdsk says it cannot run because the disk needs to be formatted.
SFC gives me:

"Windows Resource Protection could not start the repair service."

This is an Intel M2 SSD (500GB) with Optane (16GB) from a Dell Inspiron 2-in-1 laptop and it just failed two days ago with no warning that I saw (my wife mostly uses it).
Is there any way to recover from an NTFS volume like this?

I'm not a Windows person, but recovery does sound promising.  The first step is to unlock the Bitlocker partition (ie get a decrypted version) which will then allow you to access the NTFS volume stored in it.   Are you able to go to Control Panel  -> System and Security -> Bitlocker Drive Encryption to see the drive and unlock/decrypt it?

Also, if you right click on the drive/partition rather then left click on it, does it offer any options related to Bitlocker?

Data recovery off a BitLocker protected drive is nearly impossible let alone one with an unknown BitLocker protected partition.

@Ramhound I respect you and am sure you are right and I've never needed to attempt recovery from a Bitlocker encrypted drive - but I can't understand why that would be the case, assuming you had the recovery key so you can unlock the drive?  Worst case scenario why could I not use Dislocker under Linux and treat it similarly  to how I might try and recover data off a LUKS encrypted partition?

@davidgo - It doesn’t sound like the author can actually mount the drive if it’s an unknown BitLocker protected partition. The drive also failed to boot which suggests the file system had a problem probably from corrupt system fields. Furthermore, file recovery is normally done by scanning the disk which is difficult with an SSD but even more difficult in that disk is encrypted. It sounds like the BitLocker header is gone, if that’s the case, file recovery most certainly will be impossible

@Ramhound - If Bitlocker is similar to LUKS in design I agree that if the header is gone, so is the contents of the Bitlocker partition  That said while trying to find information about the Bitlocker header I stumbled across https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/97390-use-bitlocker-repair-tool-recover-encrypted-drive-windows.html - which looks like it could provide some hope.  (To the OP - if the drive contents is valuable, do a bitcopy of the encrypted drive before attempting this type of recovery)

@davidgo - I am pretty sure all FDE works the same, there is some small portion of the disk, which contains the information to decrypt the drive provided the password is known.

@davidgo I can see the drive in the BitLocker Drive Encryption, but it only lets me turn on BitLocker.  I wonder if the Data Partition that is marked as BitLocker encrypted is doing that as a default when it cannot be read, rather than actually being encrypted.  OSX shows it as an MSDOS FAT partition, but won't mount it either.  The data is likely not valuable, as we store most things on a fileserver but I don't like to just let go of it without a fight.

As a last resort I may put the drive back in the laptop, boot to windows recovery media, and try to repair (which hadn't occurred to me because I figured I could just get the data from it in the way I'm trying now.

The first step I'd take is to clone the disk - this will give you some indication how bad the disk is (At least if you used ddrescue - again I'm a Linux person). It would also give you a better fallback position.  There is merit in using the original system for recovery as it might assist with unlocking the drive thanks to TPM.  Trying to fix the NTFS system until you have decrypted/unlocked the partition is a fools errant at best and could make things a lot worse. Focus on getting the partition unlocked first.
